# Android Studio git check in author name

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, android-studio

I use Android Studio with Bitbucket(over Git) for my repositories. I generally get the author name on the revision history as my name (not my Bitbucket username). When I installed Android Studio in a new computer and pushed for the first time, it showed a dialog asking for Git Username and email.
Now all my check ins have author as the username. I am not sure how to change the setting, how can I configure the VCS author settings in Android Studio?

Comment: This is still a valid question - Android Studio here shows a list of half-a-dozen committers, but I want to drop entries from the list.  I understand that a similar issue exists in IntelliJ, which has some bearing on Android Studio.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I don't think there is any UI for changing this in Android Studio, but you can change this from the command line:

```
git config user.name <your user name>
git config user.email <your email>
```

Add --global if you want this to apply to all Git repositories on your machine.

Comment: I should add. "<your user name>". In quotes

Answer (score 29):

As stated in answer above and link below we can achieve commit results but we need to use `--global`

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

Answer (score 7):

Like Martin mentioned above, running

```
git config user.name <your user name>
git config user.email <your email>
```

with or without

```
--global
```

did not solve this problem for me either. Where he has multiple authors that he wants to prune I couldn't get a single author on that list to be accepted, even though everything worked fine from the command line. In Android Studio I would always see

```
Error:No existing author found with 'username'
```

with no option to enter a git username or email. While not necessarily a fix, I found a way around my problem by manually doing the initial commit on the command line. After that I was able to commit from within Android Studio without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

i has same problem.
you just need to change your name in Bitbucket or gitlab to name you enter in author.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when prompted for Author on Android Studio -

```
your git username <your git primary email>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the username and your email that will be displayed as a contributor in your workspace like GitHub or GitLab or Bitbacket.

Like this

[image]